# How can I associate .bashrc files with bash highlighting in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

If I just add the `.bashrc` extension in the "Style Configurator" for bash it doesn't work, there's no syntax highlighting. Presumably, this happens because `.bashrc` isn't `file.ext` but rather just `.ext`

Is there another way to get this to work?

Comment: Adding `bashrc` to the "User ext." box in Style Configurator > bash seems to work fine for me, albeit I had to restart Notepad++ to get it to start highlighting.

Comment: You're right, it works. The mistake I made was to add `.bashrc` to the extensions instead of just `bashrc`. Silly me.